# SQLite Database Copy Appears Corrupted When Generated by Device and not Emulator

Tags: android, database, sqlite, copy, corruption

First I want to say thanks to everyone that reads this.  Stackoverflow is an amazing site and you guys help me out with answers everyday in the form of questions already submitted.  You all rock!

My problem:

I'm working on a database app that I'd like to back up the database at certian points so I can save the data I've collected in database over time, during development.  So to save the database to accessible memory I've followed this page:

[How can I pull databases off my android onto my desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202064/how-can-i-pull-databases-off-my-android-onto-my-desktop)

..and the above code is working great in the emulator (I can use DDMS to pull the copy of the database to my PC and view it using SQLite Database Browser).  However when I run it on an actual device, SQLite Database Browser can't read it.  To extrapolate, the copy is being created just fine on the SD card, but when I copy to my PC from my device and view it, I get nothing, SDB can't understand it or something.  However when I use an emulator, I can copy it off using DDMS and view all the tables just fine with SDB.

Using WinMerge to compare the two raw database files (one generated by the device, one generated by the emulator both running the same code) I can see there are formatting differences, but nothing that looks corrupted, but I'm not 100% sure.  The android metadata and SQL sequence tables appear to be in there (albeit in different orders), as well as my custom table.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to debug this?  I'm not sure where to start since it seems to work perfectly on the emulator.  Also, I've run the emulator at the same android release (2.3.3) as the device, so I'm am *pretty sure* they are using the same SQLite engine.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try opening this database with different SQLite [clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers).

If that doesn't work, the next step may be to try finding an SQLite [database file](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html) validator and/or to run the standard SQLite client in debug mode (but to be honest, I don't even know if those two last options are even possible).

Comment: This fixed it.  Using the firefox extension db viewer allowed me to look at the databases that I couldn't view in the other tool.  Thanks for the resources and time.