# Where does Android keep SqliteDB of an application runs on a tablet?

Tags: android, sqlite

I could not find the sqlite db file of the application that I am developing runs on a tablet (not on emulator). Please anyone share with me that where does android keep db file of an application. And how do I export it to the computer? And finally is there any tool that can parse an sqlite expression even if it has no db or table? I mean it will only check the phrase and will say the phrase is available to run or not.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, application's database files are not available on non-rooted devices. You can either use a rooted Android device, or Android standard emulator, or Genymotion (see https://www.genymotion.com) in order to be able to access database files of your app.

Answer (score 1):

It keeps it in a private embedded linux folder that's based on your application name, but that  only the userid of your application can access.

There is no way for you to copy that file directly unless you root your tablet. In the emulator, that file is directly accessible, but the emulator is a special case.

**That being said**, there is a [programmatic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375498/sqlite-database-copy-appears-corrupted-when-generated-by-device-and-not-emulator/7375904#7375904) to pull out the data from that database and reconstruct it on the SDcard to pull it back on your PC (that solution is not perfect, but at least it's better than nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Nope, You can't access the DB of the device (eithr phone or Tablet) via ADB or any other third party Eclipse plug-in.

This was restricted because of security, but you can access it if you root your Tablet or Phone, which is again most people don't prefer to do.

or you can choose to [make the db in sdcard](http://www.anddev.org/creating_database_on_sdcard_-t7817.html) (which recomended when the db is too huge).